# Why are finite differences of static input variables used to calculate the Jacobian? (OpenMDAO 2.4)

Tags: python, openmdao

I have been using the SLSQP algorithm to run some MDO problems with `ExplicitComponents` only. Each component has a runtime of around 10 seconds and 60-100 input variables. Most of the input variables are static input variables that will remain constant during the entire optimization. The static input variables originate from an `IndepVarComp`. The `ExplicitComponents` are black boxes, so no information is available on the partials.

I noticed that when the Jacobian is calculated in the `compute_totals()`, the components are linearized with respect to all their input values. In the `compute_approximations()` a finite difference is calculated over all the input values, including the static input values. So, my question is: why is a finite difference calculation performed over these static input variables? As the values remain constant, I’m not sure why this information would be useful?

Furthermore, if I understand it correctly, the components are linearized to get the sub-Jacobians, which are then used to calculate the total Jacobian. However, is it possible to directly calculate a finite-difference over the entire group instead of linearizing each component? With the runtimes of my components and amount of input variables, it will take a long time to perform the linearization of each component. However, the optimization problem has only 3 design variables. So, if I could perform three finite difference calculations over the entire MDA to calculate the total Jacobian, the total runtime will decrease significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions in reverse order:

1) Can you FD over the entire model instead of each individual component? Yes!

You can set up [FD over any group](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.4.0/features/core_features/working_with_derivatives/approximating_totals.html) in your model, including the top-level group. Then the FD is taken across that group rather than across each component in it. 
We call that computing a semi-total derivative, because in general you can select a sub-group in your model, in which case the FD is approximating a total-derivative across that group but that total-derivative is still effectively a partial-derivative for the overall model. hence semi-total derivative.

2) Why is a finite difference calculation performed over these static input variables?

In theory, you're correct that you don't really need partial derivatives of the inputs that can't change. As of OpenMDAO 2.4, we don't handle that situation automatically though, and we don't have plans to add that in the near future. However, the framework is only taking FD across the partials you tell it to. It sounds like you are declaring your partials like this:

```
self.declare_partials(of=['*'], wrt=['*'], method='fd')
```

So you're specifically asking the framework to compute all those partials. Instead, you could specify in the `wrt` argument only the inputs you know are actually changing. Of course, this is mathematically incorrect because there is a derivative wrt to the static-inputs. If someone later on connects something to those inputs and tries and optimization, they would get a wrong answer. But as long as your careful, you can specifically ask for only the partials you wanted from any component and simple leave the non-changing inputs as effectively 0.